# Foreign keys to different existing entities are not being saved on update of referencing entity

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, foreign-key-relationship

I have a POCO `A` entity referencing a `B` entity, let's say `b`. I want `A` to reference a different exising `B` entity, let's say `bb`.

These steps:

```
var b = // get existing b from somewhere out-of-context
var a = new A { B = b }
dbcontext.Set<B>.Attach(a.B);
dbcontext.Set<A>.Add(a);
context.SaveChanges();
```

generate an insert statement for `a` as expected with the `B_ID` foreign key properly set to the primary key ID of `b`. These subsequent steps:

```
var bb = // get existing bb from somewhere out-of-context
a.B = bb;
differentdbcontext.Set<B>.Attach(a.B);
differentdbcontext.Set<A>.Attach(a);
differentdbcontext.Entry(a).State = EntityState.Modified;
differentdbcontext.SaveChanges();
```

result in no change to the persisted data. The update statement *does not include* the `set B_ID = ...` as expected.

I'm doing something simple wrong as I've had other scenarios like this working before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting the state to `Modified` only has an effect on scalar properties but not on your navigation properties. I assume that `B_ID` is not a property in your model but only the foreign key column in the database not being exposed to your model.

In this case you can update the relationship only by leveraging the automatic change detection of Entity Framework. One approach - and I would call this the standard approach - is to load the original `A` *including* the original `B` from the database, set `a.B` to your new `bb` and then save the changes:

```
var bb = // get existing bb from somewhere out-of-context

differentdbcontext.Set<B>().Attach(bb);
differentdbcontext.Set<A>().Include(x => x.B).Single(x => x.Id == a.Id);

a.B = bb;

differentdbcontext.SaveChanges();
```

If you don't want to load the original from the DB some trick programming is required:

```
var bb = // get existing bb from somewhere out-of-context

if (  (a.B == null && bb != null) 
   || (a.B != null && bb == null)
   || (a.B != null && bb != null && a.B.Id != bb.Id)) //take care not to attach
                                                      //two objects with same key
{
    if (bb != null)
        differentdbcontext.Set<B>().Attach(bb);
    differentdbcontext.Set<A>().Attach(a);
    a.B = bb; // EF will detect this change
}
else if (a.B == null && bb == null)
{
    // create a dummy a.B
    a.B = new B(); // it doesn't matter which Id
    differentdbcontext.Set<A>().Attach(a);
    a.B = bb; // = null -> EF will detect a change
}

differentdbcontext.SaveChanges();
```

Or similar. The idea is to change the reference after attaching the objects so that change detection will send an update of the FK column to the database.

Exposing foreign keys as properties into your model will make this situation much easier. Setting the state to `Modified` would work then because FK properties are scalar.

Comment: I should clarify that `A.B` gets set to `bb` upon deserialization of the `A` DTO sent from the client. So there is no real assignment to `A.B` that occurs prior to using `differentdbcontext`. Is there an explicit way of telling EF *that* property changed without doing an assignment?

Comment: @Kit: No, there isn't. Telling EF explicitely that a property has changed is only supported for scalar and complex properties, not for navigation properties/relationships. It's one of the weak points of independent associations (= no foreign key properties) and the main reason why FK associations (= exposing foreign keys) have been introduced in EF 4.

Comment: Accepted the answer because it's basically right, but I can't believe the torture I'm going to have to go through to get this to work right with a generic repository interface over EF.

Comment: I wonder if it can be simplified into some helper method AttachIfNotAttached(Entity e)

Comment: @Vitalik - I have such a method, which I use as part of a generic repository implementation. All my attempts at implementing it haven't worked. It looks like I need a generic way to do the assignment afterwards.